# Is it possible to define a private variable outside of the range in c#/unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am trying to force a variable to be within a certain range. The variable is defined as a private float with a range, below is a simplification of what i am attempting:

```
[Range(0.0001f,1f)] private float myFloat;
```

I want to initialise this variable using an initialisation function like this:

```
private void Initialise(float myFloat){
    this.myFloat = myFloat;
}
```

My question is if i use the Initialise function will an exception be thrown if the value is outside of the range, or should i just define the range within the initialisation function?

Comment: Attributes do not enforce values going in to a field.

Comment: Inside your Initialise-function you could check if the value is inside the range. If not, you don't change your property.

Comment: why don't you just try it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others have already answered about it's lack of enforcement on values going into the field I would like to recommend some solutions.

You could always try making it a property and checking on setter like so:

```
private float _myFloat;
private float myFloat {
    get {
        return _myFloat;            
    }
    set {
        if (value > max || value < min) throw new Exception("");
        _myFloat = value;
    }
}
```

Or in your initialize if your goal is to limit to a range you could use the clamp functionality

```
this.myFloat = Mathf.Clamp(myFloat, min, max);
```

Lastly if you want it to throw an exception you could write your own Clamp or Exception styled method.

**Edit:**
I'm adding in an example for usage with the Range attribute as well. this example is compile time fine, runtime maybe(?). [Conceptually you should be able to do something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/retrieving-information-stored-in-attributes) either with the Range attribute or your own [Custom Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes)

```
[Range(0f, 0f)]
public float myCustomValue;

public void GetAttribute()
{
    RangeAttribute attribute = (RangeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(myCustomValue.GetType(), typeof(RangeAttribute));
    float minValue = attribute.Minimum;
    float maxValue = attribute.Maximum;
}

public class RangeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public float Minimum { get; init; }
    public float Maximum { get; init; }
    
    public RangeAttribute(float minimum, float maximum)
    {
        this.Minimum = minimum;
        this.Maximum = maximum;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could show how to get the `max` and `min` values from the attribute.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've added an example using attributes.

Comment: Thank you. I fleshed it out a little more for you.